# Ionic release not installing after implementing facebook login

Tags: ionic-framework, facebook-login

I have install facebook login plugin to my ionic application and generated hash and added to facebook developer console. I have generated debug application and it works well by installing.

But when i generate release apk it is not even installing after uploaded to google drive as it is installing when i generate debug app.

I have not generated debug keystore from the start of my app, i just has generate release keystore only.

Comment: "it is not even installing" did you do a clean install ? Meaning did you uninstall any previous versions of the app (debug or release) and install again ?

Comment: Yes, i have removed the previously installed and then tried to install new one.